# Java trying to build a countdown but integer always returns 0

Tags: java, android-studio, timer, countdown, timertask

I am trying to build a countdown such as "time left: 10 ". 
To achieve this I tried using a `TimerTask` but my problem is that the integer jumps to 0 instantly instead of counting down from 15 as I want it to and I just can't figure out why.

Any help is appreciated.

**Relevant code:**

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int verbleibendeZeit = 15;

private void countdown() {
        countdownText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        final Timer progessTimer = new Timer();
        final TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (verbleibendeZeit > 0) {
                    verbleibendeZeit--;
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        countdownText.setText("Zeit übrig: " + verbleibendeZeit);
                    }
                });
                if (verbleibendeZeit == 0) {
                    progessTimer.cancel();
                    countdownText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        };

        progessTimer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: `while (verbleibendeZeit > 0) { ...}` will only end if `verbeibendeZeit` is zero or negative, that is, will loop until the rest time is zero, and only then the rest of the code will be executed. Just decrement the variable once (if greater than zero), the `Timer` will call the method every second.

Comment: @user15244370 how did I miss that....Thank you!

Comment: its probably too late to code... but I would also do `if (verbleibendeZeit <= 0)` to cancel the timer...

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is the problem:

```
while (verbleibendeZeit > 0) {
    verbleibendeZeit--;
}
```

Change it to:

```
if (verbleibendeZeit > 0) {
    verbleibendeZeit=verbleibendeZeit-1;
}
```